# mergJSON-GPL-1.0.8.zip missing windows .dll

Tags: livecode

I downloaded MergJSON from mergext.com to use with RunRev's Livecode, The .zip file mergJSON-GPL-1.0.8.zip doesn't contain a windows .dll file. Has support for windows been dropped?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the Linux build got dropped from the archive too. I'll sort it out ASAP.

Comment: Thanks for the updated 1.0.9.zip

Today I tried recreating an iOS app, and it keeps failing to create. I keeps saying "linking for armv7 failed with Undefined symbols"

Mac Mini 10.9, Xcode 6.0.1, I've tried Livecode 6.6.4, 6.6.5, and 7.0

Is this an issue with the mergJSON.lcext file?

Comment: Hmm... that's odd. Yes it's the lcext file. 1.0.9 definitely has iOS 8 and 8.1 builds in it.

Comment: Here is the exact message:  linking for armv7 failed with undefined symbols for architecture armv7; "__libinfoptr_mergJSON"

Comment: And you're definitely using the lcext file from 1.0.9?

Comment: I downloaded the 1.0.10 file today, and have successfully recreated my app for iOS and Windows environments. Thanks for the quick responses and updates.